# Items missing from d3 map visualization

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to recreate M. Bostock's famous [Choropleth example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) but with coloring by state instead of by county. I have it mostly working, however for some reason the first few states are not rendering. From researching other questions, I think it may be [selectAll issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043720/d3-plot-missing-the-first-item-in-an-array) or an issue with how d3 is parsing indices, but I can't seem to make sense of it.

Below is the specific function where I go in and render the states:

```
function testMap(error, us){
    if(error) throw error;
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value = num.get(d.id)); })
      .attr("d", path)
    .append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return state.get(d.id) + ", " + d.value; });

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "states")
      .attr("d", path);
```

[Here's a working JSFiddle with my issue](https://jsfiddle.net/bLxsg5zt/3/)

PS: I should note, I am attempting to use d3 v4 for this example, which I have learned is quite a departure from v3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

In your CSV, you have some states with just 1 digit for the ID.

```
state       abrev   id  value
Alabama     AL      1   0.113771056
Alaska      AK      2   0.634948665
Arizona     AZ      4   0.022697068
Arkansas    AR      5   0.762050795
California  CA      6   0.99979688
Colorado    CO      8   0.606026214
Connecticut CT      9   0.165650662
Delaware    DE      10  0.950772614
//from Delaware on, all IDs have 2 digits
```

Those are exactly the states with problem, because `num.set(d.id, d.value)` won't match the IDs of the paths, which have 2 digits (01, 02, 04, 05 etc...).

**Solution**: add a zero to those IDs:

```
.defer(d3.csv, "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2465343/test.csv",
        function(d) {
            if (d.id.length == 1) {
                d.id = "0" + d.id;
            }
            num.set(d.id, d.value);
            state.set(d.id, d.state)
        })
    .await(testMap);
```

Now you have the correct IDs, as if this was your CSV:

```
state       abrev   id  value
Alabama     AL      01   0.113771056
Alaska      AK      02   0.634948665
Arizona     AZ      04   0.022697068
Arkansas    AR      05   0.762050795
California  CA      06   0.99979688
Colorado    CO      08   0.606026214
Connecticut CT      09   0.165650662
Delaware    DE      10  0.950772614
//...
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r95e113L/

You can, of course, fix this without any code, just opening the CSV in any text editor and adding the zeros for those IDs manually.

Another even shorter fix: convert the IDs from strings to integers:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { 
    return color(d.value = num.get(+d.id)); 
})
```

And here is the respective fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/entraop9/

Comment: This is the better answer, identifying the precise cause with a solution where mine only shows where the problem was surfacing. If I ever make it to the sportsmanship badge it might be solely because of you Gerardo, you are two for two where we both answered so far I think (a ways off still)

Comment: @AndrewReid Your answer (just upvoted it) also has its value, showing OP how to verify a value before using it.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! To bypass the whole 0 padding issue, is there a way to convert the ids to integers when reading both the map and csv? Or can javascript not force types like that?

Comment: @M_Corn yes, sure, that's another way to fix it, check my edit. It can be done with a single + sign.

Answer (score 1):

I have good news, the issue is not how you are appending the map features. If I change this:

```
 .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value = num.get(d.id)); })
```

to:

```
.attr("fill","steelblue")
```

I can see everything: https://jsfiddle.net/h6b2bjrt/

If I change that line to:

```
attr("fill", function(d) { console.log(num.get(d.id)); return color(d.value = num.get(d.id)); })
```

I can see that seven features are not defined where they need to be, this could be what is throwing your drawing off. If I replace it with:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { if(num.get(d.id) == undefined) { return color(d.value = 0); } else { return color(d.value = num.get(d.id)); } })
```

which replaces undefined values with zeros, [I see all the states](https://jsfiddle.net/06v7znm8/)